# Elementor clash with buddypress when posting internal links

Tags: wordpress, iframe, elementor, buddypress

I have created a buddypress forum, and was wanting to share an internal link. The rest of the site has been built using elementor (for inexperienced users). They want to share an internal link on the buddypress blog, but it keeps presenting an iframe that hosts HTML code (rather than just posting the url). I've looked in the dev tools, and this shows up:

```html
<iframe loading="lazy" class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" security="restricted" title="“Read the latest issue of the NGCV E-News and sign up for the next issue.” — NGCV" src="https://ngcv.org.uk/read-the-latest-issue-of-the-ngcv-e-news-and-sign-up-for-the-next-issue/embed/#?secret=20fPza27Rl" data-secret="20fPza27Rl" width="600" height="692" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Any ideas how I can find the iframe css and disable it?